# Clifford algebra and exterior algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, exterior-algebra, clifford-algebras

Let $E$ be a finite dimensional real vector space with $E^*$ its dual, and let $\langle \; , \; \rangle$ be an inner product on $E$. For any $e \in E$, denote by $e^* = \langle e, \; \rangle \in E^*$ the element dual to $e$ via $\langle \; , \; \rangle$.

We define a homomorphism

$C: E \to \text{End}(\Lambda^* (E^*)) \; , \; e \mapsto e^* \wedge i_{e},$

where $i_e: \Lambda^*(E^*) \to \Lambda^{*-1}(E^*)$ denotes the contraction (interior multiplication) induced by $e$. Observe that $C(e)$ is a degree-preserving endomorphism of $\Lambda^*(E^*)$. It is claimed in [this article](http://www.numdam.org/item/AST_1992__205__7_0/) on page 65 that one has

$$ C(e)^2 = \langle e,e \rangle \cdot \mathbb 1_{\Lambda^*(E)}$$

To me, this equality seems absurd. For example, if $e_1,e_2$ are two orthonormal vectors, then one has $i_{e_1}(e_2^*) = \langle e_2,e_1 \rangle = 0$, so that in particular $C(e_1)^2 e_2^* = 0 \neq e_2^*$. I believe that there must be something fundamental that I misunderstand, but I can't see what it is. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I don't see that claim on that page. Are you talking about the statements in equation (4.16)?

Comment: Yes, exactly. It follows from the second equation in the case $e = e'$, doesn't it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are interpreting the definition (4.15) incorrectly.  $\hat{c}(e)$ is the sum of $e^*\wedge(-)$ and $i_e(-)$, similarly $c(e)$ is the difference.

Comment: Thank you! This was very easy to misread.

Comment: Wow, the typesetting is atrocious.

Comment: Unfortunalety, it is the only book on that topic I know that goes as in-depth as it does.

Comment: Yeah, it took me half a minute to realize this is what was intended.  What finally made sense is that it can't be $e^*\wedge i_e$ otherwise there is no point defining the two $c$'s which are just -1 times each other.

Comment: Exactly. I realized quite quickly that it couldn't be what I originally thought it was, for the very reason you mentioned. However, your "obvious" solution somehow didn't come to my mind.